# Calculate screen size with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to get the screen size with Vue

I have this until now, but nothing works for me now

```
data: () => ({
WindowsSize: '',
 methods: {

 elem() {
  this.size = window.innerWidth;
  return this.size;
 },
 mounted() {
  if (this.elem < 767){ //some code }
  }
 })
```

the goal is that with a my div show and hide elements

```
<div v-if="WindowsSize== ''" />
```

some way to get am, searching the web hasn't worked for me so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to show/hide elements based on screen width. That
could be done more simply with [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries):

```html
<template>
  <div class="large">...</div>
</template>

<style>
/* hide by default */
.large {
  display: none;
}

/* show when screen is at least 600px wide */
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .large {
    display: block;
  }
}
</style>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/PoWdrNW?editors=1100)